# Regex end of string problem

Tags: php, regex

I want to match the last "order by" in the string (e.g. $matches[1] = doo.time) I can sort of see the problem is with the `(.*)` part but not sure what to change it to as it needs to be any character, any ideas?

```
$sql = "SELECT foo FROM blah ORDER BY foo.date ORDER BY doo.time";

if (preg_match('/ORDER BY\s(.*)$/i', $sql, $matches)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches); exit;
}
```

Comment: If regex is not critical to you, you could use the likely faster strripos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can greedily match (without capturing) everything before it. This will force the rest of the pattern to only match the last ORDER BY. This worked for me.

```
$sql = "SELECT foo FROM blah ORDER BY foo.date ORDER BY doo.time";

if (preg_match('/(?:.*)ORDER BY\s(.*)$/i', $sql, $matches)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches); exit;
}
```

Comment: `(.*)$` will do just as well instead of `(.*?)$`.

Comment: @Tim: Yes, thanks. That was left there from my earlier experiments with `/ORDER BY\s(.*)$/i` and `/ORDER BY\s(.*)$/iU`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking for the column name, try this:

```
if (preg_match('/.*ORDER BY\s(.*?)(?:ASC|DESC)?\s*(?:LIMIT.*)?$/i', $sql, $matches)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches); exit;
}
```

Comment: @fire: Will your order bys have any `ASC` or `DESC` keywords?